# NTFS Read-Write App for Snow Leopard / Lion

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, software-recommendation, ntfs

I am looking out for an app that can read and write NTFS partition.

I am using Snow Leopard, and will update to Lion (very soon).

I have heard about [NTFS Mounter](http://ntfsmounter.com/), but I think there will be other apps which are much better than NTFS Mounter.

Please suggest a fine app, once that you have personally tried and tested.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Paragon NTFS ( http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/ ) which I've been using since Leopard and now with Lion. It's good, but I do get the occasional problem once every couple of months. I'd rather buy a supported product as I use it quite often. If it was occasional, I'd probably got for NTFS-3g or other free options.

Comment: Btw, a CD with Paragon NTFS is often included when you buy an external hard-drive, so you might already have it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the trial version of [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) and it seems pretty solid. Paragon NTFS (linked in mekondelta's answer) is another paid utility, but I haven't tried it. And there's [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/), which is based off of the open source MacFUSE project, but I haven't tried that either.

Answer (score 0):

I use The community edition of [NTFS 3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) for some time now. It' works nicely - only complains now and then when the drive was not unmounted properly on windows. Given it's open source and free well worth a try. (it's also from tuxera)

Though I wouldn't trust it to repair a drive and use it only when I have to.